# What are these two intruders into Rudbeckia seedlings home?

Tags: identification, seedlings

I started black-eyed Susan (Rudbeckia hirta) seeds in a tray - you can recognize her seedlings by hairy true leaves. However, I noticed there is another type of seedlings of unknown origin, that looks differently:

[image]

Apart from having different leaves, they are also legier. From different angle:

[image]

There is another one that appears to be of the same kind in another cell:

[image]

From different angle:

[image]

They are the only two of such kind in my 44-cell tray.

What are they, and what to do with them?

Comment: Why are you starting random seeds?

Comment: Graham, I am not starting random seeds - the whole tray is intended to be Rudbeckia's. Her seeds are tiny, and I did not know any way to distribute the but in a sort of random fashion over the tray. Seed germination was better than expected, so I ended up with several seedlings per cell.@Graham

Comment: Sometimes the potting soil has weed seeds in it. It happened to me with Florabest from Lidl and Florasol from Kaufland. I just remove them when it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a type of lettuce... *Lactuca sativa*

Below is a photo of our pot of “Summer Harvest” seedlings.

[image: Lettuce “Summer Harvest”]

I not certain what variety you have.

My recommendation is to carefully remove these seedlings from your tray of Rudbeckia and place them in a small pot of their own to grow on. Once you’ve transplanted them, don’t forget to give them a drink of water with a half strength seaweed extract to help alleviate transplant shock.

Once the lettuce seedlings are larger, you can plant them in the garden or into a larger pot.

If you need advice on how to remove seedlings from the tray, let me know and I’ll update my answer.